# Convert XPATH to CSS Selector tool

Tags: css, xpath

How can I convert xpath to css selector?
For example: this is xpath

```
//th[contains(text(), 'model number')]/following-sibling::td
```

How can I convert it to css selector? Is there a tool that enables me to do that conversion

Comment: If done manually, what would be the css selector for that xpath?

Comment: I couldn't convert it to a CSS selector.

Comment: Seems css selectors are able to operate only on attribute values so in that case it couldn't be possible.